# Rendering intial Component with Backend-Endpoint call

Tags: java, reactjs, frontend, fetch-api

I‘m trying to add a login response component to my application.

I‘d like to call the endpoint at the initial loading of the SPA.
The Endpoint calls a Java Class, which verifys the user (already working).

I don‘t know how to call the Endpoint initially and render a Response Modal after.

I am new to react and FetchAPI.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just don't show it until the data is loaded:

```
function X(){
  const [data, setData] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(setData)
  }, [])
  return <>
    {data && <Modal data={data}/>}
  </>
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of "r => r.json()"?

Comment: to get the response as json (there's also text(), arrayBuffer() and blob())